# Fixed Depreciation Table For Each Year in Python

Tags: python

I'm making a Fixed Depreciation table based off the formula:

```
Fixed rate = 1 - ((salvage / cost) ^ (1 / life))
```

I have this piece of code so far:

```
def FixedRateDepreciationTable(salvage,cost, life):
    rate = 1 - ((salvage / cost) ** (1 / life))
    print("Year       Depreciation       Book Value at the year-end")
    dv= cost * rate
    cost= cost - dv
    print("{0:4}    {1:>18}    {2:26}".format(1,"$"+str(round(dv,2)),cost))

FixedRateDepreciationTable(1000, 100000, 10)
```

Which gives the result:

```
Year       Depreciation       Book Value at the year-end
   1             $36904.27             63095.73444801933
```

I'm unsure how to get the rest of the years to print out along with the first year. How can I get all the years to print out with the Depreciation and Book Value using the code I have now?

Comment: You need to learn about loops.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I've got the formula for depreciation right (I've been taught different formulas to the one you give) but you can adapt this logic if necessary.

Essentially what I'm doing is turning `FixedRateDepreciationTable` into a *[generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)* so that it will yield the depreciation and new value for each year, up until the end of the product's usable life.

In the main body of code, I iterate over this generator and print each value.

```
def FixedRateDepreciationTable(salvage, cost, life):
    rate = 1 - ((salvage / cost) ** (1 / life))

    for year in range(1, life + 1):
        dv = cost * rate
        cost -= dv
        yield year, round(dv, 2), cost


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Year\tDepreciation\tBook Value at the year-end")
    for year, depreciation, new_value in FixedRateDepreciationTable(1000, 100000, 10):
        print("{0:4}\t{1:>18}\t{2:26}".format(year, depreciation, new_value))
```

**Output**

```
Year    Depreciation    Book Value at the year-end
   1              36904.27           63095.73444801933
   2              23285.02           39810.71705534973
   3              14691.85            25118.8643150958
   4               9269.93          15848.931924611135
   5               5848.93                     10000.0
   6               3690.43           6309.573444801932
   7                2328.5          3981.0717055349724
   8               1469.19            2511.88643150958
   9                926.99          1584.8931924611134
  10                584.89           999.9999999999999
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a loop:

```
for year in range(1, life):
```

Indent the lines of code to put them in the loop.